# How can I comment on an erroneous comment?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

My answer to a Visual Studio/MFC question has been criticised as "not providing an answer to the question", and recommended for deletion - see https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26688971.

But I *did* answer, writing

> "... moving it to the other string table fixed the problem ..."

This would have saved me several hours, if I had read it, so I believe it is a helpful answer.

I have tried all the options I can find on the various Stack Overflow pages, but can discover no way of pointing this out ... apart from (perhaps?) this!

Comment: None of the users who were involved in the deletion of that answer are moderators.

Comment: eh, wording the answer better may help... omit the "me too" portion and just provide the solution. Not knowing *why* the solution worked is very much a problem for the credibility/usefulness of the answer... but it'd still be a decent answer.

Comment: Moderators on Stack Overflow are elected and have a diamond next to their name. Users are empowered to curate the questions and answers themselves. You can edit your post to provide more information.

Comment: My apologies to the Moderators for the mistaken adverse criticism.  At the time, I thought that was who the commentators were!

Answer (score 13):

Please do not reply to the comments. That accomplishes nothing. Even if you managed to persuade the commenters, they've already cast their vote for removal of the answer.

Instead, take the comments as a signal that your answer wasn't sufficiently clear, and ***edit*** your post to clarify how it answers the question. That will stop others from casting votes of their own for removal of the post, and, more importantly, will fix the problem at its source.

Note that this is generally true on this site whenever you receive a comment: your first instinct should be to edit the post to address the concern mentioned in the comment, rather than reply to the comment itself.

Comment: I have feeling that instincts can be guided.. A kind of message what is shown when you click "add comment" button under other comment to own post: "It looks like you are trying to reply to a comment. Consider to edit your post instead, so that valuable information you are about to post will stay in case comments are purged".